# How to create a list of numbers

Tags: python, list

Please help me to create a program that output a list  of possible numbers containing all the numbers in the range N (N is the input number), but there should be no consecutive numbers

Example:

```
N=4
```

The range of `n = 0,1,2,3`

```
1032 False because (1 behind 0) and (3 behind 2) 

1230 False because (1 behind 2) and (2 behind 3)

2031 True because there no two consecutive numbers one behind the other
List=[1302,2031]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @jonrshape, you meant SO instead of OS? :)

Comment: Hint: the `itertools` module will calculate permutations for you, like this: `list(itertools.permutations("0123", 4))`, which is the hard part. Then you can pick out the ones you want.

Comment: Your question is also very unclear, I don't understand your example

Comment: Please note that SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; see the [help].

Comment: @CoryKramer I want to create a program that output of list of all numbers that we can generate from the range of n(n is the input number) but we can't make two consecutives number one behind the other ex:

Comment: So what have you tried? people will help if you have some code that doesn't work. But no one will write the code for you. This is not a code writing service

Comment: You have to explain to the audience here what is the logic behind True and False. Currently it's so confusing. By asking unclear questions, you waste everyone's time, including your in comprehending the unclear. You keep repeating "but we can't make two consecutives number one behind the other ex: –" but doesn't explain why for example 1234 is False and 2413 is True. And what is this `ProbList`. What to do with it?

Comment: You say you want 0, 1, 2, 3 and then there is 4 in your examples. Why is that?

Comment: Based of your question the last instance should be False also right? If we are looking in the range of 0,1,2,3 (N=4) then how is 2413 True? Don't you mean in range of N-1?

Comment: @EdekiOkoh sorry I correct it

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:

```
n = int(input())
l = list()
i = 0
for j in range(1,n+1):
   if j == 0:
      l.append(j)
   elif j % 2 == 0:
      l.insert(0, j)
   else:
      l.append(j)

print(l)
```

This actually works only when 'n' is odd.
I hope you can figure the even case.
If not please let me know